# React native footer background color in ios (with Native base components)

Tags: react-native, native-base

[image]

I want to change this footer color that appears in iPhone 11 pro max (both black and white parts)

I've seen the answers with fragment and safearea, but I've wrapped my screens with header and content components from native base and I'm looking for an answer that would adapt with them.

This is my current layout :

```js
  import React from 'react';
  import { Container, Content, Header } from 'native-base';

  <Container>
    <Header
      androidStatusBarColor="#F4F6FF"
      iosBarStyle="dark-content"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#F4F6FF',
        height: 45,
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
      }}
    />

    <Content contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
       {children}
    </Content>
  </Container>
```

Comment: is `Container` a custom-component? ...

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli Its from "native-base"

Comment: @MinaFa have you tried adding backgroundColor to the Container component?